# How do we find the dimension of this particular vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $F$ be a splitting field for the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A\in F^{n\times n}$. Denote by $S(A)$ the set of eigenvalues of $A$. Denote by $F^n$ denote the set of n-dimensional column vectors.

Let $M(A,\alpha):=\{v\in F^n|(A-\alpha I)^n v=0\}$. There was a result in a certain paper that the dimension of this particular vector space is equal to the algebraic multiplicity of $\alpha$. However, they kinda jumped on the proof of this particular thing. Can someone enlighten me how it happened that way? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, Sir, my bad. I already edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer will make things clearer and giving the context:

The *geometric multiplicity* of an eigenvalue $\alpha$ is the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace $\ker(A-\alpha I)$.
 Now, in determining the *Jordan normal form* of a matrix, we're led to consider the sequence of nested subspaces: $\ker(A-\alpha I)^i\subset \ker(A-\alpha I)^{i+1}$ $(i=0,1,\dots,)$: 
$$\{0\}\subset\ker(A-\alpha I)\subset\ker(A-\alpha I)^2\subset\dotsm $$

The sequence of corresponding dimensions is involved in the number of Jordan blocks of a given size.

It happens this sequence  is, for the  first values of $i$ a (strictly) increasing sequence, then it stabilises, for dimensions reasons.

The smallest integer $m$ such that $\ker(A-\alpha I)^m= \ker(A-\alpha I)^{m+1}=\cdots$, is equal to the multiplicity of $\alpha$ as a root of the the characteristic polynomial

Comment: I still can't imagine the thing, Sir. Is there any other way to compute for the dimension of that vector space?

Comment: Well,  you may compute the successive powers  of $A-\alpha I$ and proceed to row reduction to determine the rank, until this rank is stable. Anyway, $m\le n$. You may take a look at [Generalized eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir.